# Magento Error: After Theme upload on Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

Just uploaded a new theme and now get the error. I cannot access the website as well as the backend.

Here is the log:

```
Trace:
#0 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#4 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#5 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(737): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#6 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(734): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#7 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(521): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#8 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(566): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->getData()
#9 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(741): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
#10 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/local/Magentothem/Revslider/Helper/Data.php(617): Varien_Data_Collection->getIterator()
#11 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/local/Magentothem/Revslider/Helper/Data.php(634): Magentothem_Revslider_Helper_Data->getAllCaptionInSlide()
#12 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/local/Magentothem/Revslider/Block/Revslider.php(26): Magentothem_Revslider_Helper_Data->initCss()
#13 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Magentothem_Revslider_Block_Revslider->_toHtml()
#14 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#16 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#17 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('ma_banner', true)
#18 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/design/frontend/ma_optician/ma_optician4/template/page/2columns-right.phtml(47): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('ma_banner')
#19 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/xxxxxx/...')
#20 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/ma_opt...')
#21 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#22 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#23 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#24 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#25 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#26 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'ma_optician4_ho...')
#27 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'ma_optician4_ho...')
#28 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#29 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#30 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#31 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#32 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#33 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#34 {main}
```

I did this but it didn't resolve the issue.

```
Navigate to the "errors" folder.

Change local.xml.sample to local.xml

You should now see a new list of crazy errors all over the Magento page - this is okay.

Open magento/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php and look for:

protected $_options = array(
'cache_dir' => 'null',
Change it to:

protected $_options = array(
'cache_dir' => 'tmp/',
Save it.
Now the final step is to go create a tmp folder in the root Magento folder.
```

Any more pointers on what's wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: The important first line of the stack trace that tells you the specific error was left off this question. Best guess is that something in the theme is messed up or the cache wasn't flushed after installing the theme.

Answer (score -1):

You have any remaned localxxx.xml if it is there, just delete and clear your cache